# Can I run Desktop and Server class in same Machine (Oracle 19c)?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have Installed Oracle 19c in my machine in Desktop class. I need to install it in the server class also. Can I have both in my machine.
And Installation guide for the Server class.

Comment: Create two virtual machines and install Oracle with a different class in each VM.

Comment: Hello Ragul, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please can you write '?' character for any question ? Can you also split your lines for readability (pressing Enter key is sufficient) ?